# How to show nested data using MVC Views and PartialViews

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The problem I am working on is very similar to the way StackOverflow is displaying Question, its comments, Posts and comments related to the Posts. The hierarchy is the same.

**How is this accomplished in ASP.Net MVC?**

So far I have this: (I have named the files similar to SO site to make my question more readable)

Views/Questions/Details.aspx

```
public class QuestionsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Details(int? questionId)
    {
        Question question= _db.Question .First(i => i.QuestionId== questionId);
        return View(question);
    }
}
```

This loads the details and display the question.

I have a user control called QuestionComment, which should display the comments for the question but I am not sure how to go about wiring it up. I have been using the Dinners solution as a guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create ViewModel for displaying Question with Comments. Something like this:

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
    public Question Question { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

your controller become:

```
public class QuestionsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Details(int? questionId)
    {
        var question = _db.Question.First(x => x.QuestionId == questionId);
        var comments = _db.Comment.Where(x => x.QuestionId == questionId).ToList();
        var model = new QuestionViewModel {
            Question = question,
            Comments = comments
        };
        return View("Details", model);
    }
}
```

your "Details" View:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<QuestionViewModel>" %>

<% Html.Renderpartial("QuestionControl", model.Question); %>
<% Html.Renderpartial("CommentsControl", model.Comments); %>
```

"QuestionControl" partial View:

```
<%@ Control Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Question>" %>

<h3><%= Model.Title %></h3>

...
```

"CommentsControl" partial View:

```
<%@ Control Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Comment>>" %>

<ul>
<% foreach (var comment in Model) { %>
    <li>
        <%= comment.Content %>
    </li>
<% } %>
</ul>

...
```

Comment: +1 like this as it relives the view of doing things fits better with the pattern IMHO

Answer (score 0):

In your view write something like this;

```
<% foreach (var question in Model.Questions) { %>

<%=question.bodyText%>

<%}%>
```

Hope this helps, if not post a comment and I'll be less cryptic.

Comment: Or,

<% Html.Renderpartial("commentsControl", question); %>

Comment: This means that I do not need to have my comments in a separate UserControl?

Comment: How will I pass the Id of the Question so that I only get the comments associated with that question?

Comment: I think the best approach is to use a seperate user control for this.  Take a look at my first comment for the RenderPartial.  You could pass in the whole comments collection with say [question.comments] or you could render a partial control and pass in the id of the question.  <% Html.RenderPartial("commentsControl", question.id);%>

Comment: Actually, I think you'll need to pass in the collection of comments to the control and not the question id.  So you need to pass that model from your controller to the view.  you can either write a custom model binder, which is quite easy, or simply create a class in your controller and pass that back to the view and then for each question pass the comments to the partial control.